# Compile Android SQLite with different encryption/codec

Tags: android, encryption, sqlite

I am trying to compile SQLite (enable SQLITE_HAS_CODEC) with encryption/codec such as the one found in wxSQLite or Libtomcrypt, so that the result build will provide an encrypted SQLite database.

But since Android security model implements a secure sandbox policy in which no app can read other apps data, will the resulting SQLite (build with encryption) work with all apps transparently and avoid secure sandbox policy, or you need to configure each project separately so that it can save encrypted data to SQLite?

I mean will it encrypt data coming from all apps to be stored in SQLite database, or it will be applicable only for one project that need to be configured for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to compile SQLite (enable SQLITE_HAS_CODEC) with encryption/codec such as the one found in wxSQLite or Libtomcrypt, so that the result build will provide an encrypted SQLite database.

I would recommend that you use [SQLCipher for Android](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/), which has done all of this for you.

> will the resulting SQLite (build with encryption) work with all apps transparently and avoid secure sandbox policy

No.

You could create your own ROM mod that replaces standard SQLite with your encryption-enabled one. However, no apps will actually use the encryption, because they will not be asking the user for a passphrase and using it. And while you could then say that you will use a hardwired passphrase, then you are adding no security, because anyone could go grab that passphrase and then use it to decrypt the databases.

> or you need to configure each project separately so that it can save encrypted data to SQLite?

Yes, and more importantly, each project will need to ask the user for a passphrase.

Comment: I am interested in creating my own ROM mod which give encryption-enabled SQLite. So if we can neutralize the passphrase problem by one way or another, which I admit is a complicated one, is there a way to allow the resulting SQLite be able to encrypt data from different apps transparently. Alternatively, can we enable that by modifying some part of the Android architecture, or there is no way since is completely related to the Linux kernel layer.

Comment: @user2139641: "is there a way to allow the resulting SQLite be able to encrypt data from different apps transparently" -- so long as your modified SQLite does not change any public interfaces used by the framework code (e.g., `SQLiteDatabase`), the framework code and apps written to that framework code should not be affected. However, I am far from expert in this sort of firmware tinkering.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your database to the SDcard/external storage, and thus other apps can read it, if they know the path. Or you can provide a lib that does it.

Comment: I think the SDcard is not as secure as the internal storage and it can be removed anytime leaving your apps without database data. I prefer to target the original SQLite database saved in the internal storage. Anyhow thanks for your suggestion.